# Reject all collations other than latin1_swedish_ci

Tags: python, mysql, collation

I have a log-in system, and when I enter a special symbol such as ○ I get this error message...

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

I think the best way to deal with this is when asking for the users username, reject inputs that are not in latin1_swedish_ci, e.g. alt codes like ☺. How would I do this? Relevant code:

```
username = input("Enter username")
password = input("Enter password")
insertData = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"  
cursor.execute(insertData, [(username), (password)])  #Execute SQL statement
db.commit()  #Commit changes
```

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci is the collation type in my database

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem coming from an HTML `<form>` that you control?  If so, it probably has (or the browser defaults to)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">.
```

Change that to accept only whatever the equivalent of latin1 is.  That is, add the following to your `form` tag:

```
accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: I am using python in an IDE, and am not using any html. I'm looking for a way to set it so pythons input("")  only accepts latin1 and rejects everything else

Comment: Check my Python tips here (but flip _away from_ utf8):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python